# why my vscode automatically launch a "Debug Terminal" at start up when connecting to a specific linux machine

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

as you can see, the "Debug Terminal" automatically start up.
everytime I reload the vscode window, another debug terminal pops up

what could be the problem?
I've looked into the "output" column but failed to find the information of who starts the debug terminal

inside this debug terminal, it's just a normal zsh shell

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

For me, it was being caused by the "iPython for VSCode" plugin. Uninstalling that plugin stopped the debug terminal from opening whenever I launched VSCode.

Hope that helps someone out there, bugged me for months.